# How to change date format from input type date in input field in reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, date, datetime, input

I'm using input type date in my reactjs project it's working fine but as I requirement I need to change date format dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd..tried but not getting any solution. 
My code is:

```
<Input
  type="date"
  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
  id="start_date"
  name="start_date"
  placeholder="Start Date"
  value={this.state.start_date}
  onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
  className="form-control"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Which library you use for input tag

Comment: @AvneeshKumarSinghal Didn't use any library.. just use input type date as above code.

Comment: please share all import library related to  this file

Comment: @AvneeshKumarSinghal as I already mention I'm using input type date... date picker coming but want to change date format..and you I'm not using any lib for it.

Answer (score 0):

> the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser
>   - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

So you probably don't need to worry about it, but you might want to change your browser locale to test it.